# Xcode 13.3 and 13.2 build for simulator but not for real device

Tags: xcode

I recently had my phone updated to iOS 15.4 and so I need to update Xcode to 13.3.

I ran into a problem where my code does build on x86_64 simulator but the same code when archiving or building to "any iOS device" hangs indefenitively no error no nothing.

I tried with Xcode 13.2 and 13.3 the only way I found to be able to build something and archive is building with Xcode 13.1. I do not know if there are compiler update or new option but I am stuck and lost a day looking for an answer.
Did sb had the problem and found a solution ?

EDIT:

I spend the day looking for what can be the cause of the problem.
I do thinks that the compiler algorithm has changed and is less performant at dealing with circular references.

My method :
I started a new project and moved all of my components one by one. Doing clean build folder and recompiling at each feature I added.
At some point my build time jumped from 5 sec to 150sec with the addition of one file that uses some other structs I added.

When removing all functions, members that uses my custom time, keeping only Strings, Ints and Arrays. My build time came back to 5sec. Adding a single reference to a custom type that I know is dependent of other tipes (its a Backoffice Model) sends the build time to the 100+ sec.

Is It possible to get to the 13.2 build algorithm ?  With that one it takes me only 30 sec to build the entire project.

Comment: On the contrary, Xcode 13.3 is _how_ you build for your iOS 15.4 device.

Comment: that's not the question here. I do know that I need Xcode 13.3 to build for iOS 15.4 devices. My problem is that with Xcode 13.3 my code does compile for simulators but never finishes the build (it just hangs there) for actual devices or for archive to be pushed to the App Store connect.

Comment: And I'm saying that no one else is experiencing this.

Comment: @matt I really doubt that, as Xcode seems to have a long history of similar issues: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687663?page=2

Comment: I have not personally experienced this issue, but have had other problems with Xcode in the past.  Sometimes cleaning the build folder helps.  I found that the build will hang indefinitely sometimes if a previous build has just failed with a certain error.  Unfortunately I don't have a solution for you, since changing the version to an earlier one seems to have resolved your issue, I would guess it's a bug with the latest Xcode update

Comment: Well I do thinks its Xcode related. I retried to compile everything. clean build folder and so. For simulator (like iPhone 11, 15.4) it takes 30-40 seconds to make a clean build. Using the any iOS device target I let the compiler run while I was off. I took 1h30 but I did got a success.

Comment: I was having the same problem until I updated to Xcode 13.3.1 and my IOS device to IOS 15.4.1.

Comment: I am using XCode  13.3.1 (13E500a). available via the Mac app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I tried with Xcode 13.4 RC and the build went successful in a reasonable time (less than 5 min as always)